# Display the number of nodes and the depth of the tree C#

Tags: c#

I put nodes inside a Treeview in visual studio. I want to count the tree nodes and the depth of the tree:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself or looked into how this can be done? Are you stuck on a particular aspect?

Comment: Are we talking about a Console App, WinForm, WPF, ASP.NET ? What Have you tried ? some code snippets would be helpful.

Comment: Looked into how this can be done.

Comment: Console App. I have an excel file and i put it inside of a treeview. The tree when i run the program is inside of the tree. But i want to know how can i display in a textbox the number of the nodes that are inside of the tree and in another textbox  the depth of the tree

Comment: You sure that's a console app?

Comment: Sorry. My bad ,it's a Windows Form Application.

Answer (score 0):

For traversing trees (or anything tree-like, really) you pretty much need recursion - a function that calls itself, until it reaches the end of every branch in the tree.

```
public int CountTreeNodes(TreeNodeCollection nodes)
{
    int count = nodes.Count;

    foreach (TreeNode node in nodes)
    {
        if (node.Nodes.Count > 0) count += CountTreeNodes(node.Nodes);
    }

    return count;
}
```

The above first adds the number of 1st level nodes to count. Then loops over nodes, and if a node has sub-nodes, calls itself, and then adds that to the count.

To test:

```
TreeView tv = new TreeView();

for (int i=0; i < 10; i++)
{
    TreeNode node = new TreeNode(i.ToString());
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) node.Nodes.Add(j.ToString());

    tv.Nodes.Add(node);
}

int count = CountTreeNodes(tv.Nodes);
```

This should return total of 110 nodes. 10 on the 1st level, and then each of those have 10 subnodes, so 10 + 10 * 10 = 110.